# Which is a better approach? How can i replace @Html.Partial with @Html.RenderAction?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, renderaction

We are converting our app from ASPNET Webforms to ASPNET MVC.  Currently we are doing small POC's on our exiting features.

We have a dashboard page that looks like below [image: Dashboard]

1. "Member Dashboard", "Account Summary" and "Plan Information" are Partial views(also strongly typed) placed on the parent "Home" Views.
2. "Member Dashboard" Partial view does not change for a user. But "Account Summary" and "Plan Information" Partial-views has to updated based on the "Plan Type" drop-down.
3. I have three different models for "Member Dashboard", "Account Summary" and "Plan Information" partial views.
4. I use @Html.Partial on the the Parent "Home" view and pass model to the partial views.

All works fine.

How can I replace `@Html.Partial` with `@Html.RenderAction` for the above scenario?  (This way I don't have to use the super-model for the "Home" View.)

How can the "Account Summary" and "Plan Information" section be updated when a user changes "Plan Type" drop-down and click Submit.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?  Can't you just call RenderAction with the correct route values and presto?

Comment: Yes, @Html.RenderAction works. My qn here is how do i update two partial views when i click on Submit?

Comment: Does it take a long time to render "Member Dashboard"? If not I would put all three in one partial view and update it all - that makes it a LOT easier...

Comment: No it does not. Since these partial views(not necessarily all 3 together) are shown on other pages as well, we decided against it.

Comment: @nfa379 I take it you want to do an AJAX call to refresh the views?  Or is a full page refresh ok?

Comment: @dbaseman - OK with both. To start with i would do it without AJAX.